# ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'user'. SQL authentification failed. Integrated authentication only

Tags: node.js, sql-server, authentication

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server PTC_PROG database. I'm using node.js, the mssql package and Visual Studio Code.
I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uvy_BlgwfLI

This is my code:

dbconfig.js

```
    const config = {
        user: 'user',
        password: 'password',
        server: 'server',
        database: 'database',
        options:{
            trustedConnection: true,
            enableArithPort : true,
            instancename : 'PTC_PROG'
        },
        
    }
    
    module.exports = config;
```

dboperations.js

```
    async function getOrders() {
        try{
            let pool = await sql.connect(config);
            let database = await pool.request().query("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
            return database.recordsets;
        }
        catch (error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    
    module.exports = {
        getOrders : getOrders

}
```

order.js

```
---------

    class Order{
        constructor(MasterItemKey, MasterItemFileName){
            this.MasterItemKey = MasterItemKey;
            this.MasterItemFileName = MasterItemFileName;
        }
    }
    
    module.exports = Order;
```

### api.js

```
    var Order = require('./order');
    var dboperations = require('./dboperations');
    
    dboperations.getOrders().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
```

I read the log:
Login failed for user ". Reason attempt to login SQL authentification failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only.

how can i set up the interface(REST API) to talk to the database.
I've already tried a lot but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: If you're getting a connection error, then go to the SQL Server's logs and find out what the true error is. Then, if you don't understand it, [edit] your question with it.

Comment: You are mixing authentication types. For SQL Server logins use `user` and `password` together; for Windows (integrated) authentication use `trustedConnection`. Don't try to mix the two together.

Comment: I read the log: Login failed for user ". Reason attempt to login SQL authentification failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only.

how can i set up the interface(REST API) to talk to the database. I've already tried a lot but haven't found anything yet.